# Windows Defender Flagging WSL As Threat

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Something annoying that has started each time I open up Windows Subsystem for Linux 1 (WSL1) is that I get the following notification from Windows Defender (I'm using Windows 10).

It says a threat was detected, called `SettingsModifier:Win32/HostsFileHijack`. This only has ever occurred when I start using WSL1 (i.e. when I open up the windows terminal). It says the affected item was `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\etc\hosts`

Is there a way I can make this stop complaining each time I start using WSL1?
I tried adding the file `SettingsModifier:Win32/HostsFileHijack` to the exclusions in Windows Defender but when I do it tells me `You can't open this location using this program`.

Comment: I have WSL running (Kali) and Windows Defender running and no conflicts.  Whitelist the file / app in WD that is causing the issue.

Comment: You should report this to Microsoft. // Maybe you can exclude the entire package folder?

Comment: @John I'd like to but I don't know how. I tried adding it to the exclusions got the error message I mentioned in the post.

Comment: I have looked around WD and do not see a way to handle WSL.  I will keep looking.

Comment: The `/etc/hosts` in a WSL instance is auto-generated, so it does seem odd that Defender would complain about the one in WSL1, but not the Windows master.  At least in my case, the auto-generated one is identical for both WSL1 and WSL2, and includes `127.0.0.1` as `localhost`, 127.0.1.1` as the Windows hostname, the contents of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, and some IPv6 default entries.  What does your look like?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds when I try to open `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\etc\hosts` in notepad++ I get a message saying it doesn't exist. When I view the one at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` I see what you describe.

Comment: From inside the WSL instance, do a `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I get nothing, nothing returns.

Comment: Ah, okay - that must be the quarantine that Windows Defender is putting on it.  You mentioned that you *"tried adding the file `SettingsModifier:Win32/HostsFileHijack` to the exclusions."*  Was that a typo?  The file to exclude should be `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\etc\hosts`.

Comment: Also curious, have you ever had to add `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to the exclusions?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I've never added anything to my exclusions.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I tried adding `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\etc\hosts` but I got the same error from Windows when I tried to add it, telling me `You can't open this location using this program`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL usually autogenerates `/etc/hosts`, and it seems to do so using several sources:

- Some programmatically generated entries for `localhost` and aliases
- The contents of your Windows host file
- Some IPv6 "nice-to-haves" for `localhost` and multicast.

It's odd that your WSL `/etc/hosts` is triggering Windows Defender, but your Windows one is not.  Have you by any chance already added `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to the Windows Defender exclusions?  Are you using it to suppress Windows telemetry or anything like that?

*Edit/Update: Conclusion in the comments is that Spybot Anti-Beacon is likely the culprit that was adding anti-telemetry host entries.  This triggers a Windows Defender warning on `SettingsModifier:Win32/HostsFileHijack`, which is excluded for the Windows host file.  However, since the WSL `/etc/hosts` is auto-generated, it can't be found/opened to be excluded.*

At least we can turn off the auto-generation, and you can try to create your own.  To turn off auto-generation:

- Inside the WSL instance, create or edit `/etc/wsl.conf`
- Add the following section:

  ```
  [network]
  generateHosts = false
  ```
- Exit the session
- Run `wsl --terminate <distroname>` (where  is the name of your instance)
- Restart WSL
- Create your own `/etc/hosts` (preferably as root under `sudo`) with, at a minimum:

  ```
  127.0.0.1    localhost
  127.0.1.1    Yourwindowshostname.local   Your_windows_machine_name
  ```

  And anything else that you need from your Windows `hosts` file (if anything), not including, of course, any telemetry blocking entries.

Hopefully that will take care of the error.

Comment: Now that you mention "suppressing telemetry" - I do use Spybot Anti-Beacon and have a setting enabled that blocks telemetry via hosts. Could that be what is causing the issue?

Comment: Absolutely.  I asked because when I searched on that malware signature, one of the first results [mentioned that blocking Windows telemetry and ads](https://mspoweruser.com/hostsfilehijack-microsoft-defender/) will trigger it.  It sounds like Anti-Beacon is able to exclude the Windows host file, but when WSL tries to auto-generate its version based on the Windows one, it triggers the Defender warning as well.  The solution should still be to disable the auto-generation, or maybe you can turn off that Anti-Beacon feature?

Comment: Thank you for explaining all that. What will be the consequence of turning off auto-generation?

Comment: When you turn off auto-generation, you should create your own `/etc/hosts`.  I'll add a minimal version to the answer.